# PHP OOP and MySQLi connection = Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::arrayQuery()

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, mysqli

Please tell me what I've done wrong? And how to work with base better? Connection works, but I can not see information from base. I just get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::arrayQuery()

I can't understand how to fix it, Google didn't help either.

```
<?php
class Proc{
    protected $DB;
    function __construct(){
        $this->DB=new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'basename');
        $this->DB->query("set names utf8");}
    function __destruct(){unset($this->DB);}
    function GetAll(){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $this->DB->arrayQuery($sql, SQLITE_ASSOC);
        return $result;}
}

$Yo = new Proc();

$users = $Yo->GetAll();
echo "All users: ".count($users);
foreach ($users as $user){
    $id = $user["ID"];
    $n = $user["Name"];
    echo "{$id} - {$n}<br/>";}
?>
```

A little fix and all work perfect! Thanks to all!

```
<?php
class Proc{
    protected $DB;
    function __construct(){
        $this->DB=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=basename", user, password);
        $this->DB->query("set names utf8");}
    function __destruct(){unset($this->DB);}
    function GetAll(){
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $this->DB->query($sql);
        return $result;}
}
$Yo = new Proc();
$users = $Yo->GetAll();
foreach ($users as $user){
    $id = $user["ID"];
    $n = $user["Name"];
    echo "{$id} - {$n}<br/>";}
?>
```

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli::arrayQuery() - I mean error message is cear, isn't?

Comment: Can you post this function `arrayQuery` if you have it

Comment: Checking http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php reveals that `arrayQuery` is not available (the mysqli class does not have such a method).  Also, it might be better to switch to PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What database are you using? `SQLite` or `mysql` ?

Because as per the [PHP DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlite-array-query.php), I guess the function `arrayQuery` can be used only for SQLite databases

Comment: MySQL 5.5.37, and connect as "mysqli". So this is not SQLite?

Comment: Nope...thats mysql database you are having, and since you have initialized "mysqli", the mysqli class does not have that method